# retrieve all rows from mysql table but group them first to remove duplication

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am retrieving all records from a table to echo them on a php page, the problem is that there are rows with similar values for 3 columns that are repeating in the table, can someone please help me with this bit of code, what do I need to group? The group by retrieved just one row, please do reply. The fields grouped by are getting repeated and the fields that are added with new records are secondarySubject and secondaryGrade

The result I get is:

```
---------------------------------

2012-2013 School ABC A-Level 
in science A

2012-2013 School ABC A-Leve
 in maths B

2012-2013 School ABC A-Level
 in Eng C
-----------------------------------
```

What I want is

```
----------------

2012-2013 School ABC A-Level
in science A
in maths B
in Eng C
-----------------------



$result2 = $db->query('

SELECT *

FROM secondaryEducation

WHERE userID = "'.$graduateID.'"

ORDER BY secondaryFinishDate DESC

');

$html .= '<h2>Secondary Education: '.$option.'</h2>';

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))

    {



        $startYear = formatDate($row['secondaryStartDate'], 'Y');

        $finishYear = formatDate($row['secondaryFinishDate'], 'Y');

        if (!empty($row['secondaryGrade']))

            $secondaryGrade = getSecondaryGradeName($row['secondaryGrade']);

        else

            $secondaryGrade = $row['secondaryGradeCustom'];

        if (!empty($row['secondarySubject']))

            $secondarySubject = getSecondarySubjectName($row['secondarySubject']);

        else

            $secondarySubject = $row['secondarySubjectCustom'];

            $score = $row['score'];

            $secondaryLevel = getSecondaryLevelName($row['secondaryLevel']);
            $levelID = getSecondaryLevelID($row['secondaryLevel']);
        if($levelID!=='7')
        {

        $html .= '



            <div class="secondaryListing">

                <div><strong>'.$startYear.' - '.$finishYear.' '.stripslashes($row['secondarySchool']).'</strong></div>

                <div>'.$secondaryLevel.' in '.$secondarySubject.' - '.stripSlashes($secondaryGrade).'</div>

            </div><!-- End education listing -->';
        }
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: And some sample data please.

Comment: I Have now, please do lemme know

Comment: Provide the php code for the for loop - what is before `$html .= '`

Comment: Trying to understand.  Are you saying that you have multiple rows with `2012-2013 School ABC A-Level` on them? But you only want to see it once?

Comment: @Andrew yes this is how i want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just before the while cycle, create an array:

```
$schools = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2))
...
```

Instead of appending to `$html`, add the strings to the `$schools` associative array:

```
if($levelID!=='7')
{
    $schools[$startYear.' - '.$finishYear.' '.stripslashes($row['secondarySchool']) . ' ' . $secondaryLevel][]=' in '.$secondarySubject.' - '.stripSlashes($secondaryGrade);
}
```

And finally, at the end, iterate the `$schools` associative array and append the strings to the `$html`:

```
foreach($schools as $group => $entries)
{
    $html .= '<div class="secondaryListing"><div><strong>'.$group.'</strong></div>';
    foreach($entries as $entry) {
        $html .= '<div>'.$entry.'</div>';
    }
    $html .='</div><!-- End education listing -->';
}
```

Comment: OH MY GOD it worked, thanks a lot, just one last thing pleaseeeeeeeeeeeeee, The secondaryLevel is still repeating itself, please how can I make it appear once as well?

Comment: I edited the answer - in the `if($levelID!=='7')` assigment I moved the variable `$secondaryLevel` from right side to the left side (from "entries" to "group")

Comment: oops just realized that the entries are repeating :( Any specific reason for that ?

Comment: it's like if there are 4 rows it's printed 4 times with one records initially and then 2, till 4

Comment: You mean that `' in '.$secondarySubject.' - '.stripSlashes($secondaryGrade)` is included in multiple groups?

Comment: 2017 - 2008 kings college A level
in Applied Mathematics - A*

2017 - 2008 kings college A level
in Applied Mathematics - A*
in Applied Business - C

2017 - 2008 kings college A level
in Applied Mathematics - A*
in Applied Business - C
in Business Studies - E

Comment: getting me? printed for one row, then the other but with two rows, then all three....... please you've taken me nearly there, please just one last bit

Comment: Yeah, I get it. You placed my `foreach` code snippet inside the `while` loop. Moving the `foreach` after the `while` loop should solve it.

Comment: BTW, in the question, there is missing end of the while loop `}`